# Ionic. How inject ionicPlatform into the service?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to inject `$ionicPlatform` abstraction into the service, but seemed I'm doing this wrong way. How should I use `$ionicPlatform` with service?

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('service', []).service('BBNService', ["$ionicPlatform", function ($http, $localStorage, $ionicPlatform) {
```

This code making $ionicPlatform undefined.

Comment: It should be `.service('BBNService', ["$ionicPlatform", function ($ionicPlatform) {` also you need to inject `ionic` into your `service` module

Comment: As you can see below, ionic and ionic.core already injected into main module.

Answer (score 1):

Inject ionic dependency & Remove $http if you not using it as follows,

```
 angular.module('service', ['ionic'])
   .service('BBNService', ["$localStorage", "$ionicPlatform", 
       function ($localStorage, $ionicPlatform) {
   }]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Comment: can you pls remove the $http & check and tell me? Whether you are getting any error or not?

Comment: angular.module('service', ['ionic'])
   .service('BBNService', ["$localStorage", "$ionicPlatform", 
       function ($localStorage, $ionicPlatform) {
   }]);   
Did you change like above?Getting the same error?

Comment: Probably you're right about $http but remove this from injectables that really not the way.

Comment: yeah I know. We are using $http to pass the URL based on our requirement. We declared it, but we doesn't used it anywhere. That's what the issue.
 http://mcgivery.com/ionic-using-factories-and-web-services-for-dynamic-data/

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because you wrong the order. (use `ionic.Platform`)

Replace with this:

```
angular.module('service', [])
  .service('BBNService', ["$http", "$localStorage", 
     function ($http, $localStorage) {
       //use this
       var $ionicPlatform = ionic.Platform;

  }]);
```

Comment: I suppose that, but I got another error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Comment: what's `protocol`? `service` is the only module in your app? You should inject `ionic` as a dependencies of `service` (if you don't have another module that inject ionic and service)

Comment: Of course ionic already injected in main module. Should I inject ionic in service as well?

Comment: I did changed exactly as in your example. Now: TypeError: $ionicPlatform.ready is not a function

Comment: Use only `ionic.Platform` without $. Check [this for docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

Comment: This giving another error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ionicPlatformProvider <- ionicPlatform <- BBNService