# Ionic. Using $http giving error Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This question is related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122341/ionic-how-inject-ionicplatform-into-the-service).
Before I did added $ionicPlatform, my service working just fine, but now there is something wrong with $http.
Here is example of injectables:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('service', ['ionic'])
   .service('BBNService', ["$http", "$localStorage", "$ionicPlatform",
       function ($http, $localStorage, $ionicPlatform) {
```

And using of $http and $ionicPlatform

```
this.tips = function () {
            var url;
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                if (window.Connection) {
                    if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.CELL_4G || navigator.connection.type == Connection.WIFI) {
                        if (this.getDayId = 0)//If Sunday - retrieve updated tips
                            url = this.host + "/tips/";
                        else
                            url = "data/tips.json";//If not - use saved data
                    }
                }
            });
            var request = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url
            }).then(
                function mySucces(response) {
                    return response.data;
                },
                function myError(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            return request;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send back the promise, doing a `return response.data` is not gonna work.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var request = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url
            }).then(
                function mySucces(response) {
                     deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function myError(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.data);
                });

   return deferred.promise;
```

And at the place where you consume this service:

```
BBNService.tips().then(
      function(data) { //success call back with data  },
      function(data) { //error call back with data }
           );
```

*Please let me know if you need more explanation on using $q; always happy to give more details.*